# How to override the delay timer on a Keynote slide during a presentation

Tags: keynote

Assume that you've set a Keynote (v 6.5.3) slide to automatically advance after 2 minutes:

[image]

This works fine - until you realise during your presentation that you've finished early and are ready to move onto the next slide.

How can you **override the delay timer**, and force the slide to move on?

Keynote ignores any key-press or slide remote, and doggedly waits the 2 minutes before advancing.

(*In PowerPoint you can set an auto-advance-after-delay, but override it during a presentation using the keyboard or a slide remote - this is the behaviour I'm trying to emulate*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> during playback.

---

**EDIT:**

These are the Navigation keyboard shortcuts for use during presentation.

[image: Screenshot of keyboard shortcuts for navigation of Keynote presentations]

Comment: Thanks for the tip - but it's not working for me on a stand-alone 2014 MBP running Yosemite and the latest Keynote. Are you using presentation mode (ie with an external display)?

Comment: Yep, same setup as you, but it seems temperamental.  It didn't work when starting the slide show at the slide in question.

Comment: I just edited the shortcut.  This works better than the option + ] shortcut.

Comment: Glad it worked!!